# Unhooking a hooked process when the hook starts a new thread

Tags: c++, hook, ipc

I created a simple hook that I installed with

```
SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, addr, dll, 0);
```

When done, I uninstall with

```
UnhookWindowsHookEx(0);
```

And then I can watch the injected DLL unload from hooked processes in the injected DLL's DllMain being called with

```
DllMain(..., DLL_PROCESS_DETACH, ...)
```

However, if my injected DLL spins up a simple thread as so:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK HookProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
...
    static bool alreadyHooked = false;
    switch (nCode)
    {
    case HCBT_ACTIVATE:
    {
        if (alreadyHooked)
        {
            break;
        }
        alreadyHooked = true;
        std::thread([&]
        {
            for (;;)
            {
                Sleep(1000);
            }
        }).detach();
    }
}
```

then the injected DLL doesn't unload. The running thread keeps it going.

What are my options to get the DLL to unload? I could use IPC to let all the hooked processes know it is time to shut down the extra thread at the time I call UnhookWindowsHookEx(), but this feels a bit redundant, since there's already some communication happening via UnhookWindowsHookEx().

Is there a way other than IPC to find out in the hooked process that UnhookWindowsHookEx() has been called and then cleanly shut down any threads I've spun up? What is it about spinning up the thread that prevents the dll unload but other things like using Minhook to splice my dll's code in does not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked this a while back and @Hans Passant basically answered it in a comment, but it then got deleted automatically due to no official answer. Felt it was worthwhile enough to bring back with an answer.

Hans pointed this out from [MS documentation on hooking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/using-hooks):

> The system eventually frees the DLL after all processes explicitly linked to the DLL have either terminated or called FreeLibrary and all processes that called the hook procedure have resumed processing outside the DLL.

So basically, yes, IPC to communicate from the hooking program to the hooked program that it's time to unload and the thread spun up needs to be stopped is the only way to accomplish this. Thanks Hans.